# Problem implementing classifier algorithm for whitespace separated words

Tags: java, algorithm, classification

I have a text and split it into words separated by white spaces.

I'm classifying units and they work if it occurs in the same word (eg.: '100m', '90kg', '140°F', 'US$500'), but I'm having problems if they appears separately, each part in a word (eg.: '100 °C', 'US$ 450', '150 km').

The classifier algorithm can understand if the unit is in right and the value is missing is in the left or right side.

My question is how can I iterate over all word that are in a list providing the corrects word to the classifier.

This is only an example of code. I have tried in a lot of ways.

```
for(String word: words){
    String category = classifier.classify(word);
    if(classifier.needPreviousWord()){
      // ?
    }
    if(classifier.needNextWord()){
      // ?
    }
}
```

In another words, I need to iterate over the list classifying all the words, and if the previous word is needed to test, provide the last word and the unit. If the next word is needed, provide the unit and the next word. Appears to be simple, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Do you have data on which unit need values before them and which units need value after them?

Comment: @Sathwick Yes, the units that need values before or after are pre-defined. In example, distance, weight, temperature needs before. Only currency need after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an implicit iterator in your for loop, but an explicit. Then you can go back and forth as you like.

```
Iterator<String> i = words.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    String category = classifier.classify(i.next());
    if(classifier.needPreviousWord()){
        i.previous();
    }
    if(classifier.needNextWord()){
        i.next();
    }
}
```

This is not complete, because I don't know what your classifier does exactly, but it should give you an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: My classifier reconigzes units and names (at moment). The category returned in the classify method is things like: Distance, Temperature, ProperName, Weight, etc. or a UNIT, if is something unit, but that don't has a value

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand you correctly. Does this code help you or can you formulate another question?

Comment: I'm trying to do with the iterator. I think it helped me. I only will finish the algorithm with it.

Comment: Using an ListIterator helped me to build the algorithm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could help.

```
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
   List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

   String previousWord = "";
   String nextWord = "";

   for(int i=0; i < words.size(); i++) {
       if(i > 0) {
           previousWord = words.get(i-1);
       }
       String currentWord = words.get(i);

       if(i < words.size() - 1) {
           nextWord = words.get(i+1);
       } else {
           nextWord = "";
       }

        String category = classifier.classify(word);
        if(category.needPreviousWord()){
            if(previousWord.length() == 0) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: missing previous unit");
            } else {
                System.out.println(previousWord + currentWord);   
            }
        }
        if(category.needNextWord()){
            if(nextWord.length() == 0) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: missing next unit");
            } else {
                System.out.println(currentWord + nextWord);
            }

        }
    }

}
```